# Benefit to keeping a record in the database, rather than deleting it, for performance issues?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, indexing

So I have a client that I am building a Rails app for....I am using PostgreSQL.

He made this comment about preferring to hide records, rather than delete them, and given that this is the first time I have heard about this I figured I would ask you guys to hear your thoughts.

> I'd rather hide than delete because deletions in tables eventually lead to table index havoc that causes queries to take longer than expected (much worse than Inserts or Updates).  This won't be a problem in the beginning of the site (it gets exponentially worse over time), but seems like an easy issue to never encounter by just not deleting anything (yet) as part of the "everyday" web application functionality.  We can always handle deletions much later as part of a Data Optimization & Maintenance process and re-index tables in that process on some (yet to be determined) scheduled basis.

In all the Rails apps I have built, I have never had an issue with records being deleted and it affecting the index.

Am I missing something? Is this a problem that used to exist, but modern RDBMS products have fixed it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3453853/832759 this is slightly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074261/sql-server-delete-slowed-drastically-by-indexes

Comment: @j03w That makes sense, but then the issue is not the speed per operation initially - but by modifying the index, does it make future lookups slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be functional reasons for preferring that records not be deleted, but reasons relating to some form of table index "havoc" are almost certainly bogus unless supported by some technical evidence.

You hear this sort of thing quite often in the Oracle world -- that indexes do not re-use space freed up by deletions. It's usually based on some misinterpretation of the facts (eg. that index blocks are not freed for re-use until they are completely empty). Hence you end up with people giving advice to periodically rebuild indexes. If you give these issues some thought, you wonder why the RDBMS developers would not have fixed such an issue, given that it supposedly harms the system performance.

So there may be some piece of Postgres-related, possibly obsolete, information on which this is based, but the onus is really on the person objecting to a perfectly normal type of database operation to come with evidence to support their position.

Another thought: I believe that in Postgres an update is implemented as a delete and insert, hence the advice to vacuum frequently on heavily updated tables. Based on that, updates should also cause the same index problems that are supposed to be associated with deletes.

Answer (score 1):

Other reasons for not deleting the records.

1. you don't have to worry about cascading a delete through various other tables in the database that reference the row you are deleting
2. Every bit of data is useful. Debugging and auditing becomes easy.
3. Easier to rollback if needed.

Comment: But if you do not cascade that delete, then you have extra records in your child tables taking up table and index space, and requiring that every query of them also joins to this parent table to see whether the row is "deleted" or not.

Answer (score 0):

Create an deleted column in your table and dont index that one.

If you update that record with deleted = 1 or deleted = o only the data needs to be rewriten,  the index doesnt have to be updated that saves lots off IO reads and IO writes

This advies goes for all modern RDBMS when they make use of B tree indexes. B tree is an very good algorithm for searching but not for updating and deleting because off high number off IO reads and IO writes thats needed to insert or update node in the node or delete notes from the tree this is also the reason why you should not "over index" your table

"Delete" an record like this

```
UPDATE table SET deleted = 1 WHERE id = 1 -- if deleted not is indexed assuming id is index as an primary key this also should be fast
```

Check if an record is deleted

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 and deleted = 1 -- assuming id is index as an primary key this also should be fast
```

Check if an record not is deleted

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 and deleted = 0 -- assuming id is index as an primary key this also should be fast
```

Comment: But that update caused the old row to be deleted and a new one created, no? So all the indexes surely have to be updated to point to the new row?

Comment: But updating a row causes the creation of a dead tuple, according to pg_stat_user_tables, right?